# Is the way of tying Tzitzit strings essential to the posek of each shita?

Tags: tzitzis

What I mean by my question is:

We know there are different ways to tie tzitzit; this can mean the way the knots are tied (i.e. the wraps between each knot) or the amount of knots.

So, to the author of each shita, do they consider their way to be *miakev* to the mitzvah, i.e., a necessary component to completing the mitzvah, or would they agree that the other ways still fulfill the mitzvah but not the best way possible?

Comment: Is there any reason to think there is one answer that applies to every opinion?

Comment: @DoubleAA the question can be read as assuming the same answer applies to every view, or, on the contrary, as assuming that it does not (which is why the question addresses "the author of each shita" individually). I recommend you read the question in the best possible light.

Comment: It need not be "yes" or "no". It can be "well this one said.... but this one said...". I am curious how the poskim felt re: other opinions.